# Html text not centering properly between buttons

Tags: html, css

I'm making an html program, and have a frame at the top of my page and I'm trying to center text between buttons in the frame, but it either works, but breaks lines each value, or just doesn't center at all.

Examples:

Not centering but is inline
[image: Output]

```
.topBar p {
    color: #AAAAAA;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline;
}
```

Centering but with line breaks:
[image: Output]

```
.topBar p {
    color: #AAAAAA;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I've seen similar questions but haven't retrieved an answer after looking all over the web, I even tried asking an ai but that didn't work either (yes I know ai's are very hit or miss). And I have tried many combinations of the two methods shown. I assume there is a way to do this but I haven't found it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `Flexbox`, Then `flex-grow` property to distribute the remaining space between the "tungsten" text and the buttons

```css
.topbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.topbar p {
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="topbar">
  <button>Button 1</button>
  <button>Button 2</button>
  <p>tungsten</p>
  <input type="search" placeholder="Search...">
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, sorry for the confusion, I'm looking to center the "tungsten" text between the left buttons and right search bar, on the x axis.
.
for example: 
%Movies% %Shows% %Music% %Youtube% (centering space) "tungsten" (centering space) %Search Bar%

Comment: Ok then. I updated the answer check now